# How to fix this error in this code for chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to use chrome's console, but I am getting this error.

I barely have experience in using chrome's console, so please try to explain the solutions to me thoroughly.

```
var hatIds = [362081769, 19027209] //This is the Ids of the hats
var PriceWanting = 1500 //This is the price


var Loop = setInterval(function(){
        for (var Id in hatIds) {
                var hatLink = "https://m.roblox.com/items/" + hatIds[Id] + "/privatesales"
                $.get(hatLink,function(data){
                        var Regex = /\<span class="currency-robux">([\d,]+)\<\/span\>/
                        var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1]
                        PriceSelling = Number(PriceSelling.replace(",",""))
                        if (PriceSelling <= PriceWanting) {
                                var Regex2 = /<a href="\/Catalog\/VerifyTransfer\DuserAssetOptionId=([\d,]+)\Damp;expectedPrice=([\d,]+)">/
                                var HatBuyId = data.match(Regex2)[1]
                                var HatBuyLink = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=" + HatBuyId + "&expectedPrice=" + PriceSelling
                                var Explorer = document.createElement('iframe');
                                function Buy(){
                                        Explorer.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
                                };
                                Explorer.onload = Buy;
                                Explorer.width = "300";
                                Explorer.height = "400";
                                Explorer.src = HatBuyLink;
                                document.body.innerHTML = "";
                                document.body.appendChild(Explorer);
                                clearInterval(Loop)
                        }
                });
        }
        console.log("!")
},0)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.success (<anonymous>:10:61)
    at o (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4)
```

What does this error message mean?

I'm not very experienced in using chrome's console, and this is someone elses' code from google i'm trying to use.

What this program is supposed to do is to go to the link generated by the ID's I provided an Roblox's standardized link system. That link is an item link. I'm trying to buy those items on Roblox for low prices by repeatedly checking if the price is low enough and buying the item.

Comment: `match` returns `null` when no match is found. Check the regex and string.

Comment: @Tushar What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: in this line `var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1]` you are trying to get access to the data array obtain from the get of the Regex but looks like it is null. It is like try to get the index 1 from an empty array.  So try to validate that

Answer (score 0):

by clicking that error you will get from  which  line the error is coming...